# Forward slash in attribute routing regex

Tags: regex, attributerouting

I am trying to write a regex that matches a route for action. But there seems to be a problem with forward slash.

This works:

```
[Route("{url:regex((da|en))}")]
www.mydomain.com/products/en

[Route("{url:regex((da|en)something)}")]
www.mydomain.com/products/ensomething
```

This does not:

```
[Route("{url:regex((da|en)/something)}")]
www.mydomain.com/products/en/something
```

Comment: because probably '/' is a special character?

Comment: forward slash is not a special character

Comment: my bad in javascript you have to escape it. :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `regex` lets you match a single segment of a URL, while the presence of a forward slash makes `en/something` two separate segments, i.e. `en` and `something`.

Try this attribute instead:

```
[Route("{url:regex((da|en))}/something")]
```

Comment: This is a partial solution for me. In other cases I have regex that could match empty string. So when the slash is outside from regex, it does not work.